# Check if colum contains one of the values of a vector

Tags: matlab

I want to go through a CSV I generated with python for my current research. This will help me to do some system analysis, my advisor doesn't know how to use python, so he asked me to use matlab in order to at least plot my results, and he can understand everything I am doing. Because this CSV will keep getting bigger through my PhD, I want to make as generic as possible to optimize my time.

This CSV creates one column called `architecture`. Down below you've the matlab code that loads the CSV and the display of the current `architecture` column.

```matlab
data = readtable('csv/genericCSV.csv'); %reading the CSV file

display(data.architecture)

-----------------------------------------------------------------

  18×1 cell array

    {'MF'  }
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNTA'}
    {'MF'  }
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNTA'}
    {'MF'  }
    {'MF'  }
    {'LNA' }
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNA' }
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNA' }
    {'LNTA'}
    {'LNA' }
```

I want to be able to if every value of this `data.architecture` is correct, this means that if every value is one of the following three: **LNA**, **LNTA**, **MF**.

I would use something like this

```matlab
validArchis = ["LNA", "LNTA", "MF"]
if data.architecture contains one of the following validArchis
    ;
else
    error("There is a non-valid archi")
end
```

How one can do that? I want ot use the vector validArchis in order to be able to simply insert a new value to this vector in the future if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ismember`:

```
correct_data = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
data = {'A'; 'D'; 'B'; 'A'; 'C'; 'D'; 'B'; 'B'}; % == data.architecture;

if all(ismember(data, correct_data))
    fprintf('data is correct\n');
else
    error('data incorrect!');
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with contains. Example

```
if(sum(contains(data.architecture, validArchis)) == size(data.architecture,1))
         ...
else
           error("There is a non-valid archi")
end
```

Contains return logical array. If all logical values are equal 1, this mean its all correct.